# CSS layout without extra 'divs'

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

I find myself using the following layout a whole heap, but it's annoying me that it's not very semantic.

http://plnkr.co/edit/qMx9S0?p=preview

What I would really like is

```
<body>
  <h1>Hi</h1>
  <nav> Nav content</nav>
  <main> Application</main>
</body>
```

Through my experimentation there is no way to make this happen without the annoying "container div". Worst still this pattern can occur inside the app further down, (replace main with say section).

I've tried using table layouts, flexbox, floats, etc. I was trying to keep it semantic so I can arbitrarily shift around the content. (eg inspired by flexboxes ordering).

I got close by using flexbox with wrapping, setting the 'header' to 100% so it wraps, while this works, I got into a situaton where the header or h1 first is not sized using the content, but some arbitrary calculation flexbox uses, causing it to be huge.

http://plnkr.co/edit/HJFUqqA6b4ldBBkgDXV6?p=preview

Attempting to make the h1 be sized to its contents `align-self:flex-start` causes it to insert a heap of whitespace after it.

What I want is almost like I imagine what the grid layout module of CSS is, but that doesn't appear to be implemented anywhere.

UPDATE:

Part of the reason it annoys me is it exists purely to support that layout. This updated plunk shows it

http://plnkr.co/edit/rJgrYM?p=preview

Here I'm going for a full length nav bar on the side, with the header sitting over the 'main' content. Semantically its all the same, just laid out differently, but note that I had to change what the div was wrapped around. This sucks in a major way, style/layout changes requiring html bad changes just feels epically unclean.

Comment: Some other semantic elements you could use are `<section>` `<article>` `<header>` `<footer>`

Comment: It's not particularly the fact that its a div, its the fact that the div exists purely to support my layout. It means nothing in respect to the document. If I was going for a different layout, the div wouldn't need to exist

Comment: Nothing wrong with having divs to support your layout.  You could try using a grid system like Susy or Singularity though.

Comment: Div (and span) carries no semantic meaning, it's meant to be used to achieve your layout.

Comment: So to be clear, you want the header to be its natural height, and 100% width of the window/screen, and the other two things to be as at least tall as the rest of the screen, or more if there's more content, and to be the same height. Is that right?

Comment: @Nit div and span carry no semantic meaning *other than* grouping, and here the grouping is undesirable, so it's reasonable to try and get rid of them.

Comment: @FlorianRivoal You're mistaken. See [the HTML5 spec draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-div-element), namely _"The `div` element has no special meaning at all."_.

Comment: @Nit Note the next sentence in the spec: "It can be used [...] to mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements."

Comment: @FlorianRivoal You seem to mistaken the word _can_ for _is_. A div doesn't necessarily carry any meaning whatsoever.

Comment: @FlorianRivoal you've nailed it with the description of the layout, and your description of why the div irks me.

Comment: @Nit, I very well could be misunderstanding semantic html/css, but to me one of the core things was to separate presentation/layout from markup/content. A div that exists purely to create a layout seems to violate that. Getting things done etc, you add the div, but my curiosity is that div makes the document look hacky, is there a css way without the hack div?. 
Taking a div carrying no meaning to its extreme, I should just wrap every element in a wrapper div?. It seems wrong :)

Comment: The point isn't that you should use more divs, it's that there's nothing wrong or hacky about using some additional ones to achieve a layout you're after.

Comment: I try to keep the html as 'pure' as possible nowadays, I sort of build the html reading it as HTML, so it should be readable/make sense there. As such adding divs to make the layout work for a different 'view' on the site seems weird, i use divs in this mindset to group things that have no semantic tag (or just to loosely say hey things here are sort of related).

Pragmatically I get that sometimes divs may need to be added to bend the display to my will, and in my markup they are now there. I just try to avoid the div soup that seems to be the rage in current sites.

Answer (score 1):

I made you this solution, by using the body as a table.

The `h1` is displayed as a `table-caption`. Therefor it is displayed above the table, and isn't include in it's height. You'll need to give it a fix height (in px, em, %, etc) and compensate that in the height of the body.

In this case I gave the header a fix height of 40px and compensated it by using the [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) method. Please note it's [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc( 100% - 40px );
}
h1 {
    display: table-caption;
    height: 40px;
    background: lightblue;
}
nav {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20%;
    background: lightgreen;
}
main {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 80%;
    background: lightcyan;
}
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cgsopd18/)

Comment: Was wanting the header to naturally fill its contents, rather than forcing it to a fixed height. Same with the "side" column. Hence the use of flex-grow

Comment: That's no problem for the side column, just remove the width from `nav` and `main`. The `header` is another story... that's the only limitation on this design, it needs a fixed height (in px, %, em, whatever).

Comment: With a fixed height header, I could probably use display:absolute on the header, and insert padding on the body to offset that. Then I wouldn't even need to use calc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about either nav or main content potentially getting taller than the screen, but you do care about nav being sized horizontally to fit just its content rather than an arbitrary length or percentage, you could go at it this way:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  height: 40px;
  background: lightgray;
}
nav {
  float: left;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: lightblue;
}
main {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

  <nav>content</nav>
  <main>Main body</main>
</body>

</html>
```

If you care about height more than width, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30025762/4805350 is a better answer.

Comment: What if I didn't want a fixed header size? :)

Comment: Once implemented, you should be able to used "height: fill" instead of the calc(100% - whatever), but support for this is non-existent at the moment afaik. Without that, I'll need to think some more how to do this. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/#width-height-keywords

Comment: Fill sounds awesome!. Unfortunately this is a question I think may be impossible to accomplish without some tradeoffs. The question was asked hoping some semantic html/css wizard knew of some display property I don't know of :)